# modal UINavigationController inside UIPopoverViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

This is my situation:

I have a `UINavigationViewController` (with a stack of `UITableViewControllers`) which is inside an `UIPopoverViewController`. This is how it looks now:

[image]

Then one of the buttons there have this action:

```
MyViewController *moveViewcontroller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
moveViewcontroller.contentSizeForViewInPopover = self.contentSizeForViewInPopover;

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:moveViewcontroller];
navController.toolbarHidden = NO;
navController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
navController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = self.navigationController.contentSizeForViewInPopover;
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;//to show it inside the popover

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[navController release];
[moveViewcontroller release];
```

Which shows the navigation controller but it not *embedded* in the `UIPopoverController like the navigation controller in the first picture. This is what I get:

[image]

Not very nice and it is not consistent with the previous interface
**Is there a way I can make my modal navigation controller be embedded in the** `UIPopoverController`?

Basically, I want to implement a similar interface as in Mail.app in the iPhone (when moving emails from one folder to another) but inside a popover.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the presentation style for the `UIViewController` you are presenting in a modal way.
I do this using the following code:

```
MyViewController* mvc = 
[[MyViewController alloc]
 initWithNibName:@"MyViewController"
 bundle:nil];
mvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
mvc.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 210.0f);
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];
```

The key line is the one dealing with the `modalPresentationStyle` - which forces the modal view controller to appear inside the `UIPopoverController`

Comment: Hummm,... my bad. I think the problem was my question. I am not only interested in the presentationStyle of the view controller but also in the chrome its toolbar and navigation bar should have. It seems that modally presented navigation controllers won't get the nice navy blue **thick** chrome around of it. :(